# In each wordpress post, get the role of the current logged-in user

Tags: wordpress

I have several posts, some written by users with authors roles and others written by subscriber role users.
I'm trying to get that if you log in a subscriber user only in their own post display, on the div that contains their own post, an additional class, but if you start the author only in that author's posts it will be displayed in the same div, which encloses all its own posts, that shows a different class than the subscriber user

```
echo $post_content;

            $user = new WP_User($post->author_id);
            $user_roles = $user->roles[0];

           echo '<div class="file-adjuntos '.$user_online_class.' '.$user_roles.'">';

                echo $this->uploads->show_uploaded_files($post->id, $post->uploads);

            echo '</div>';
```

This above what it does is show the role of the user who put the post, to all the posts, own and not own the current user, and what you want is that the role will only show an additional class in the div of the current user's posts.
I hope you understand what I'm looking for. Thank you so much for your help. Best regards.

Comment: make it like $user = get_current_user_id();

Comment: or wp_get_current_user() ;

Comment: Dear thank you for responding, so this I must add above $user = new WP_User($post->author_id); right?

Comment: Thank you very much, it is getting closer and closer... The suggestion you passed to me earlier caused the current user's role to be added as a class within the div, but I still need that class to only be displayed in the connected user's own posts.
Or even if it wasn't the role of the current user, otherwise any class also helps me

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're initiating a new user with every post, and you don't want to.

Replace your code with this:
echo $post_content;

```
        $user = get_current_user_id();
        $author_id= $post->post_author;
        $user_roles = "";
        if($user ==  $author_id)
        $user_roles = $user->roles;


       echo '<div class="file-adjuntos '.$user_online_class.' '.$user_roles.'">';

            echo $this->uploads->show_uploaded_files($post->id, $post->uploads);

        echo '</div>';
```